# Ruby on Rails - Controller changes not getting recognized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tomcat

I seem to be having a problem where I make changes to a method in my `Controller` class, and it does not seem to get picked up by `Tomcat`.

I've tried putting `debug` in it, I even changed the name of the method, and as a last resort - I renamed the `Controller` source file on our `Linux` machine, yet it seemed the original code keeps running.  Yet, I have no idea where it is getting at the code.  I assume something is getting cached somewhere?

I've tried restarting the `Tomcat` Server, and flushing the Cache on the `Mozilla Browser` (Cntr - F5), yet it seems to keep running the old code.  If it ran the modified code, it should have crashed.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat doesn't run rails.  I would guess tomcat is running as a proxy that forwards requests to rails.

Do a `ps aux` on your system (what's the OS?) and look for a process that says `rails` or, failing that, `ruby`.

Comment: Ok, The Ruby on Rails app gets deployed as a web app.  Tomcat deploys it.  I tried both ps -ef | grep ruby and ps -ef | grep rails, and I don't see them showing up.  Is it possible somehow this data is getting cached, and is controlled through some type of environment setting?

Comment: Also, I might be usiing JRuby on Rails (if that matters)